# X intercept of a log-log linear model in R using lm ()

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, regression-coefficients, logarithm

A linear regression on dependent and predictor variable was run on simulated data after log transformation.

```
x <- rnorm(423, mean = 55, sd = 12)
y <- rnorm(423, mean = 1.44, sd = 0.3)
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
mod <- lm (log(y)~log (x), data = dat)
summary(mod)
```

[image: Summary output]

Question:

Is the x intercept in this summary log 0.186 or 0.186? The slope estimate I think is 0.0424. Can this model written as follows::

ln (y) = ln 0.186 + 0.0424 * log (x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intercept and slope are as stated in the R output. R is not trying to trick you! The fitted model is

log(y) = 0.186 + 0.0424 * log(x)

On the unlogged scaled, the fitted model is

y = exp(0.186) * x^0.0424

Comment: Thank you so much!